# How to collect text input in flutter_web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I created flutter_web app based on [hello world example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/tree/master/examples/hello_world) and [retrieve input example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input).

It does not work: cursor is blinking, but when I type nothing happens. 
My code is [here](https://github.com/polina-c/spike1), and it is hosted [here](https://spike1.codemagic.app/#/).

I use Chrome. Flutter configuration:

Flutter 1.7.8+hotfix.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 20e59316b8 (7 weeks ago) • 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
Engine • revision fee001c93f
Tools • Dart 2.4.0

What can be wrong?

Comment: I had the same problem I added a hintMaxlines and it worked .nuts be greater than two .but I think in 1.9 it's fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [hello_world](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/tree/master/examples/hello_world) example is outdated today.

For some time the [flutter_web](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web) was frozen, but now the repository is under active development and it is extremely undesirable to use master branch for education.
For these purposes, I advise you to use these relatively stable packages:
[flutter_for_web](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_for_web) and [flutter_for_web_ui](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_for_web_ui).

To do this, follow two steps:

In `pubspec.yaml` change dependencies from

```
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any
```

to

```
  flutter_for_web: ^1.0.0
  flutter_for_web_ui: ^1.0.0
```

and completely remove `dependency_overrides` section.

In `*.dart` files replace

```
import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_ui/ui.dart';
```

with

```
import 'package:flutter_for_web/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_for_web_ui/ui.dart';
```

Comment: In the near future, perhaps everything will change, because recently, Flutter team announced a [new](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) approach, and `flutter for web` will be integrated into the main flutter package. Stay tuned...